# regex to validate to capture 5 different repeating digits

Tags: regex, validation

I have a regex which validates repetitive numbers for example
numbers like `111-111-1111 or 2222222222 or 333.333.3333` are returned as no match.

However numbers like `1234567789 or 789-234-5671` are match. I am unable to validate numbers like `1234512345 or 456-784-5678`.

Can someone help me update my regex so that it can also validate and return no match for numbers like `1234512345 or 456-784-5678`?

My current Regex is

```
^(?=(?!([0-9])\1{2}[-. ]*\1{3}[-. ]*\1{4}$))\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$
```

Comment: What is wrong about `456-784-5678`?

Comment: it turns out to be repetitive number 456-784-5678 --> 45678 get repeated twice

Comment: Can you remove the hyphens before trying to match with a regex? What language are you using? Can you use a custom function for validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using some pre-processing before validating numbers with hyphens as it seems impossible to consume the hyphens and use back-references with them to check if they have already been matched since that might never happen.

If your code is in JavaScript, you can use this:

```js
function validateNumber(str) {
  var re = /^(?=(?!([0-9]+)\1))(?=(?!([0-9])\1{2}[-. ]*\1{3}[-. ]*\1{4}$))\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/gm; 
 if ((m = re.exec(str.replace(/-/g, ''))) !== null) {
    return true;
 }
  return false;
}

var case1 = validateNumber('1234512345');
var case2 = validateNumber('456-784-5678');
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "1234512345: " + case1 + "<br>456-784-5678: " + case2;
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: The main thing is that you cannot validate phone numbers with variable number of groups with hyphens... You should use a masked text box Iin asp.net, and only handle digit-only numbers. Even if we try creating all possible cases for the current scenario, it will be very difficult.

Comment: yeah that's what even i thought 
however with the current Regex i.e.^(?=(?!([0-9])\1{2}[-. ]*\1{3}[-. ]*\1{4}$))\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$

I am able to validate only a scenario where in all 10 digits are repeated for example the Regex will fail 111-111-1111 or 111.111.1111 but how would I also want numbers like 111-111-1789 to fail.

There should not be more than 7 repetitive numbers.  How can i update the current Regex

Comment: It seems the regex you have just provided is invalid. Please check out this one: https://regex101.com/r/jM3aT5/1.